# kubectl edit not working if I add an environment variable without double quote

Tags: yaml

I have a running `k8s` cluster. I want to change the image in it and also want to add couple of environment variables.

I tried using kubectl `edit -f file.yaml` and changed the image name and also added the env variable but the editor is constantly refusing the save the changes. The reason is that I can't add a value `yes` without putting `yes` in double quotes i.e. `"yes"`. Why is it?